# Для чего так пишут?

Tags: php

Для чего ставят две скобки в проверках и не только?
Пример кода:

```
if (($b = ...) instanceof ...) {}
if (!(isset($a))) {}
```

Можно вадь написать так:

```
if ($b = ... instanceof...) {}
if (!isset($a)) {}
```

Comment: Смысл первого выражения без скобок поменяется. Вот поэтому и пишут

Comment: А во втором возможно было раньше выражение длиннее, но в процессе рефакторинга стало понятно, что достаточно только isset, а скобки забыли удалить

Comment: А что именно в первом поменяется? Он ведь и другом варианте будет так работать, не?)

Comment: Просветляться https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php